# How to track ananomus user activity in my website using salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I need to track the activities of anyone visited my website in salesforce.
I could not find any of these in documentations or even does provide?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: i didn't find anything so i haven't write a single code